# No error but not writing into firestore. The code works in 7.9.1 but this is 7.14.1. Is this the error?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write into Firestore using Javascript but it doesn't work although there is no error. I am using 7.14.1 version. This code ran properly on 7.9.1 so I don't know if this is the error.

```html
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
            <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
               https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
            <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
```

I try to console log before reading data, it works but the console log after reading data does not work.

```html
function retriveid(){
           fireauth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
           if (user) {
               var user = fireauth.currentUser;
         
           if (user != null) {
           user.providerData.forEach(function () {
               console.log("Firestore loaded");
               const songname = document.getElementById('songname');
               const singername = document.getElementById('singer');
               const youtubelink = document.getElementById('ytlink');
               const audiolink = document.getElementById('aulink')
               console.log(categoryname.value, songname.value, singername.value, youtubelink.value, audiolink.value, user.uid);
               firestore.collection("song").doc("Rock").set({
                  song_name: songname.value,
                  singer_name: singername.value,
                  youtube_link: youtubelink.value,
                  audio_link: audiolink.value
               })
               .then(function(){
                   console.log("Document successfully written!");
               })
               .catch(function(error){
                   console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
               })
           });
         }
         } else {
         // No user is signed in.
         console.log("not yet log in")
         }
         });
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Doug i have the same error, only you need modify the link in "...firebase-app.js" to "...firebase.js"

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

the function ..listAll() works correctly. It will help you a lot, I had to consult several sources, i leave you an example:

```
storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/'+idReport);
storageRef.listAll().then(function(result) {
    result.items.forEach(function(imageRef) {
    // And finally display them
    displayImage(imageRef);
    });
 }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle any errors
 });

 function displayImage(imageRef) {
     imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
     console.log("url", url);
     }).catch(function(error) {
     console.log("error", error);
     });
 }
```